# Object doesn't support property or method parseJSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Please find below the javascript which loads when main page is loaded.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

       $.post('../business logic/NewsLogic.php', null, function(response) {
             var respObj = $.parseJSON(response);
             if (respObj != null) {
                 alert('I am here ');
             }
});
```

I can't able to parse JSON i got error that object doesn't support property or method  parseJSON

/* below is the sample PHP */

```
  $newsDAO = new NewsDAO();
  $newsInfo = new News();
  $respArr = array();

  $respArr = $newsDAO->showAllNews();
  print json_encode($respArr);
```

where respArr is an array which contains Elements.

Comment: You don't need to parse an already parsed JSON.

Comment: Please post the EXACT error you get, not your summary of what it sort of sounds like.

Comment: The error you are supposedly getting doesn't match your code.

Comment: You might want to `console.log()` that `response` value so that you can see what's in it.

Comment: Would you happen to be using a version of jQuery [older than 1.4.1](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you post the $.post response?

anyway, i think it will be better to use $.ajax with json as dataType like:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
type:'post',
        url: '../business logic/NewsLogic.php',
        data: 'somequerystring',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(jsonObject) {

        }
        })

    });
```

Comment: You may need to use method as `POST`

Comment: Also, you could specify the json datatype using the $.post method, you don't have to go to $.ajax to achieve that.

Comment: true. iv'e edited the message (but that's of course just an example code)

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.parse method

in your code it would fit like

```
var respObj = JSON.parse(response);
```

*********edit*********

Most browsers support JSON.parse(), which is defined in ECMA-262 5th Edition (the specification that JS is based on). Its usage is simple:

```
var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}',
    obj = JSON.parse(json);

alert(obj.count);
```

For the browsers that don't you can implement it using json2.js.

As noted in the comments, if you're already using jQuery, there is a $.parseJSON function that maps to JSON.parse if available or a form of eval in older browsers. However, this performs additional, unnecessary checks that are also performed by JSON.parse, so for the best all round performance I'd recommend using it like so:

```
var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}',
    obj = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
```

This will ensure you use native JSON.parse immediately, rather than having jQuery perform sanity checks on the string before passing it to the native parsing function.

source : [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Still JSON is undefined on javascript page

Comment: @Neo `JSON && ...` should probably test with `window.JSON` or `typeof JSON !== 'undefined'`. Testing `JSON` alone will throw an error if it hasn't been declared. Member operators and `typeof` can be used to avoid that.